# What to do when there are unrepresentative answers on a question

Tags: discussion, answers

[How do Buddhists that think of karma figuratively do so about rebirth?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41314/how-do-buddhists-that-think-of-karma-figuratively-do-so-about-rebirth)

I can't say I understand the newer answer, but the first is just a personal opinion that is completely ruled out by centuries of scholarship both western and otherwise.

We do need better / different answers, for the sake of Buddhism tbqh

Answer (score 1):

The question seemed to be asking for people's personal opinions -- and if/given/assuming a non-standard ("not what is ordinarily meant") understanding of the doctrine.

I don't understand the question, but I guess it's on-topic even if it's confused/confusing.

Anyway, given that as a starting point, I don't think we can or need complain about the answers.

If you don't like an answer I'd usually invite you to post a better one -- I'm not sure I can recommend that (i.e. answering it) for this question though, it's not clear to me what the OP is asking -- and also not (don't expect to provide "a better answer") if you're the OP yourself.